# Where can I find simple and small Javascript lightbox plugins or tutorials?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know of a plugin or tutorial for making a simple lightbox to display a simple HTML form?

Comment: yes, pretty much any lightbox plugin. there's no specific lightbox *just* for forms, or *just* for this or *just* for that (there are for images only, though but that's beside the point).

Comment: Simple simple simple?

Comment: Just for a simple HTML form. No extra features needed such as showing images, videos, changing images, etc... Just a simple HTML form.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm the title says dialog, but the question says lightbox.

For a dialog, you can use [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

For a lightbox, you can use [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: Didn't know how to call it, I just want to display a simple HTML Form. no extra functions so its smaller.

Comment: @OscarGtz Just put the `form` inside of it. There are examples on both of the sites.

Answer (score 0):

I like [Shadowbox](http://shadowbox-js.com/). It's a jQuery plugin, so you have to be running jQuery; but it can display just about anything you want it to: HTML, videos, images, whatever. If you're moderately HTML/CSS savvy, it's easy to install, use, and style.

It also allows you to download versions...that do whatever you want it to. So if you only want it to display HTML, you're good. Just download that bit, et voila.